# Variable inside dictionary value is unchanged even though same variable outside dictionary is changed. Why?

Tags: python, dictionary, variable-assignment

I have a dictionary `restaurants` and want to change the value of `opening hours` and `closing hours` in a nested list in `restaurants` depending on the day inputted by the user.

```
opening_time=0
closing_time=0

##snippet of the dictionary 
restaurants={"Macdonald's":\
             \
             [{"Monday":[700,2400],\
               "Tuesday":[700,2400],\
               "Wednesday":[700,2400],\
               "Thursday":[700,2400],\
               "Friday":[700,2400],\
               "Saturday":[700,2400],\
               "Sunday":[1000,2200]},\
              \
              "Block XXX, #01-XX",\
              "Fast food restaurant known for its all round excellent menu.",\
              \
              ["Breakfast",[opening_time,1100],\
               {"Egg McMuffin":"$1",\
                "Hotcakes":"$1",\
                "Big Breakfast":"$1"}],\
              ["Lunch/Dinner",[1100,closing_time],\
               {"Double Cheeseburger":"$3.20",\
                "McChicken":"$3.95",\
                "Big Mac":"$4.70",\
                "Chicken McNuggets (6pcs)":"$4.95",\
                "McWings":"$4.95"}],\
              ["All Day",[opening_time,closing_time],\
               {"Fillet-O-Fish":"$4.60",\
                "Corn Cup":"$1.95"}]]}
```

I want the code to loop through and print all the restaurants and menus while indicating whether said restaurants and menus would be available for a user inputted time.

```
for key in restaurants:  #key refers to restaurant name
    print("","",sep='\n')
    if day_now in restaurants.get(key)[0].keys():  #check if restaurant is open on that day
        opening_time=restaurants.get(key)[0][day_now][0]  #set opening and closing hours to those on that day
        closing_time=restaurants.get(key)[0][day_now][1]
        if time_now>=opening_time and time_now<closing_time:  #check if restaurant is open within that time period
            status="Open"
            open_restaurants.update(restaurants)
            print(key,"Status: "+status,"Opening Hours Today:"+str(opening_time)+" to "+str(closing_time),\
                  "Location: "+restaurants.get(key)[1],"Description: "+restaurants.get(key)[2],sep='\n')
            for i in range(3, len(restaurants.get(key))):  #goes through the menus the restaurant has
                print(restaurants.get(key)[i][1][0]) #prints 0
                print(restaurants.get(key)[i][1][1]) #prints 0
                if time_now>=restaurants.get(key)[i][1][0] and time_now<restaurants.get(key)[i][1][1]:  #check if menu have
                    print("")
                    print(restaurants.get(key)[i][0]+" Menu: Available","Item: Cost:",sep='\n')
                    for item in restaurants.get(key)[i][2].keys():
                        print(item, restaurants.get(key)[i][2][item],sep=' ')
                else:
                    print("")
                    print(restaurants.get(key)[i][0]+" Menu: Unavailable","Item: Cost:", sep='\n')
                    for item in restaurants.get(key)[i][2].keys():
                        print(item, restaurants.get(key)[i][2][item],sep=' ')            
        else:
            closed_restaurants.update(restaurants)
            status="Closed"
            print(key,"Status: "+status,"Opening Hours Today:"+str(opening_time)+" to "+str(closing_time),\
                  "Location: "+restaurants.get(key)[1],"Description: "+restaurants.get(key)[2], sep='\n')
    else:
        closed_restaurants.update(restaurants)
        status="Closed"
        print(key,"Status: "+status,"Opening Hours Today:"+str(opening_time)+" to "+str(closing_time),\
                  "Location: "+restaurants.get(key)[1],"Description: "+restaurants.get(key)[2], sep='\n')

print(opening_time) #prints the correct opening and closing hours
print(closing_time)
```

However, the `opening hours` and `closing hours` variables in the dictionary could not be assigned to the desired values in the loop and remained as they were first assigned outside the loop.

Directly printing the variable names showed that the new values were assigned successfully.

Could someone help me with the issue here? Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure what you would expect for output here. Which part of the code do you think should alter the output you get in the print statements, and what would you expect it to print?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use this simple example to make clear where your assumptions are wrong:

```
var = 1
lst = [var]
var = 2
print(lst)
```

What should this print, `[1]` or `[2]`? It will print `[1]`. What you have here is not a list of variable references, it is a list of integers. You took the value `var` had, and put that into a list. A copy, if you want.

What about this?

```
a = 1
b = a
a = 2
```

Again, `b` is still `1` after this. You took what was written at the location where `a` is stored, and put it in the location where `b` is stored.

**You need to actually update the values inside the dictionary, it is not enough to update `opening_hours`.**